An application to product formula of multiple integral
It is well-known that from Nualart's book, two multiple integrals can be expanded into a sum of multiple integrals, i.e.,
$$I_n(f)I_m(g)=\sum_{i=0}^{m\wedge n}i!C_m^iC_n^iI_{m+n-2i}(f\otimes_ig),$$
where $f\in L^2(T^n)$ and $g\in L^2(T^m)$.
In fact,when $f=g=\bf{1}_{\{x_j,x_{j+1}\}}$ and $m=n=1$, I can deduce that
$$I_1^2(\mathbf{1}_{\{x_j,x_{j+1}\}})=I_2(\mathbf{1}_{\{x_j,x_{j+1}\}}^{\otimes2})+\mathbb{E}[u(t,x_{j+1})-u(t,x)]^2$$
where $u(t,x)$ is the mild solution to stochastic heat equation.
However, when I consider the case of higher order, I can not get the result in the proof of Proposition 9 of Pathwise analysis and parameter estimation for the stochastic Burgers equation, that is
$$I_1^4(\mathbf{1}_{\{t_j,t_{j+1}\}})=I_4(\mathbf{1}_{\{t_j,t_{j+1}\}}^{\otimes4})+4I_2(\mathbf{1}_{\{t_j,t_{j+1}\}}^{\otimes2}\otimes_1\mathbf{1}_{\{t_j,t_{j+1}\}}^{\otimes2})+\mathbb{E}(u(t_{j+1},x)-u(t_j,x))^4.$$My idea is that I can express the $(I_1(\mathbf{1}_{\{t_j,t_{j+1}\}})I_1(\mathbf{1}_{\{t_j,t_{j+1}\}}))^2$, but it fails when I put the previous result into it.
Any answer would be appreciated
I apologize beforehand if this question is trivial or my reasoning is naive.
